# In shell script, unable to access variable outside after reading from a file in while loop

Tags: shell, sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# Read in classpath
if [ x"${JAVA_CLASSPATH}" != x ]; then
    classpath="${JAVA_CLASSPATH}"
else
    classpath=""
    while read file; do
        classpath="${classpath}:${JAVA_APP_DIR}/lib/$file"
    done < ${JAVA_APP_DIR}/lib/classpath
fi
echo classpath is ${classpath}
```

I am trying to build the classpath by reading from a file, however the classpath variable cannot be accessed outside the while loop. Please specify a way to access classpath variable outside the while loop.The result of the echo statement.

```
echo : classpath is
```

PS: I saw other questions similar to this, I am not using any pipes as mentioned in those questions. My code reflects the answers specified for those questions and yet I am still facing the issue. Also this is a shell script not bash.

Comment: Please show how you're testing this. Are you running `./yourscript` and then trying to use `"$classpath"`? If so, then the problem is that even though it sets the classpath correctly, it does that *in the shell executing the script*, not the shell that *started* the shell that executes the script.

Comment: ...if your code had a `echo "$classpath"` at the end, and *that* didn't reflect changes, that would at least demonstrate how you're testing your results.

Comment: BTW, consider running `sh -x yourscript` to run the script with logging enabled, and editing those logs into the question.

Comment: (As an aside, you don't need the `x`s -- `[ "$JAVA_CLASSPATH" != "" ]` or `[ -n "$JAVA_CLASSPATH" ]` would work just as well; with any POSIX-compliant `test` implementation, the `x`s are needed only if you're using `test` operations that are marked obsolescent -- see the `OB` sigils -- in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I updated the question with the testing. I cannot access $classpath variable outside the while loop, thats the problem. Inside the while loop, I echoed the classpath and it looks perfectly good but an echo outside resulted in nothing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am running the script as ./run.sh.

Comment: `echo : ` is in your output? That's curious.

Comment: Can you create a reproducer someone else can run to see this problem themselves? (Right now this isn't quite a standalone [mcve] since it requires setting `JAVA_APP_DIR`, creating a `classpath` file inside the directory named, etc). Something that can be run online at an interpreter such as http://ideone.com/ would be ideal.

Comment: See for example https://ideone.com/CcbtLx -- you'll note that the `echo` there shows the classpath correctly set, even after the `while` loop exited.

Comment: @africandrogba, what's the value of JAVA_APP_DIR? Can you do `[ -r "${JAVA_APP_DIR}/lib/classpath" ] || echo "cannot read ${JAVA_APP_DIR}/lib/classpath"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I copied the exact same code you mentioned in the link in the run.sh file. I ran it as ./run.sh. It resulted in as "classpath is  ". Thats the output for the exact same code. So I cant whats wrong. I cant get the classpath outside the while loop.

Comment: @africandrogba, can you cause the problem to happen at ideone.com, or somewhere else I can see it happen myself?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thats the problem. The same code that is working in ideone.com is not working when I run it on my linux box. Is it due to any version of shell that runs the code?

Comment: @africandrogba, ...no POSIX-compliant shell will have this problem. That said, you can certainly try running with some different/known shells -- do you have the same issue with `bash -x ./your-script`? `sh -x ./your-script`? `exec -a sh zsh -x ./your-script`, run by bash (to tell zsh to use POSIX-compatibility mode to execute your script)?

Comment: ...if it only happens with `sh` and none of the others, then we can try to dig into which specific implementation of sh you have -- these days, dash is the most common, but dash is POSIX-compliant and won't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `${JAVA_APP_DIR}/lib/classpath` doesn't exist.

Compare the following two similar bits of code, (only the first lines differ), tested under the *POSIX* compliant `dash` shell:

1. Input file *dummyfile* exists.

   ```
   echo baz > dummyfile
   unset foo
   if false
   then : 
   else while [ -z "$foo" ] ; do
            foo="bar"
        done < dummyfile
   fi
   echo "=$foo="
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   =bar=
   ```
2. Input file *dummyfile* doesn't exist.

   ```
   rm -f dummyfile
   unset foo
   if false
   then : 
   else while [ -z "$foo" ] ; do
            foo="bar"
        done < dummyfile
   fi
   echo "=$foo="
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   dash: 65: cannot open dummyfile: No such file
   ==
   ```

   The contents of the `while` loop were never run.

---

Note that the code is a little odd:

- The `while` loop always runs *once* and exits, because `$foo` was `unset` and then is reset.
- There's a `done < dummyfile`, but no `read` to input anything from it.  Yet even though there's no `read` command, the existence of that file, combined with the `<` redirection, determines whether or not `$foo` is set.
- Even an empty file would work:

  ```
  unset foo
  if false
  then : 
  else while [ -z "$foo" ] ; do
           foo="bar"
       done < /dev/null
  fi
  echo "=$foo="
  ```